# trouble understand basic sql statements

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Im stuck on a sql statements and need some help. Im new to database and access 2007 so i dont know all the syntax perfectly, any guidance would be great thanks

Some info

```
Teacher = [CourseN, Quarter,TeacherName]
Course = [CourseN,CourseName, Nunit)
Section = [CourseN, Quarter , DayTime,  RoomN]/ Examples of DayTime: M2:00AM, 
W4:50PM, and T8:00PM. Note that DayTime is represented as a string.
Student = [studentName, CourseN, Quarter]
```

The question

```
13. List the CourseN and Quarter of every course taught by two 
different instructors in the same quarter ordered by the CourseN in descending order.
```

The Teacher Table

```
CourseN Quarter TeacherName
1   Winter 2011 Karen Reed
1   Winter 2011 Sun     <--- cant add this one which i need to make it   work
2   Spring 2005 Salloum
3   Spring 2005 Karen Reed
4   Spring 2005 Salloum
5   Winter 2011 Sun
```

The thing about the second one is it wont let me put duplicate courseN in my database table because its either a index, primary key, or relationship so I dont know what to do since i cant input it in my table

**Edit**: I deleted the first problem since i solved, so there isnt to much in the post

Comment: For the second one, you'll need to join your course table with your instructor table (I assume that you have one), get a count of instructors for each course, and use GROUP BY and HAVING to find the courses where the instructor count is two.

Comment: @BobRodes, Wouldnt i do where the courseN  count is 2, since its asking 2 different teachers teaching the same course? And even if i do that i cant insert that information in my teacher table

Comment: No, you'll do where the teacher count is 2, since you're talking about 2 teachers teaching one course.  You probably have another table that relates the teachers to the courses, and you'll need to use that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this.

For the first query you will need to Join the tables "Course" and "Section" by the course number, which is the key. Now, I don't think you need to do any string manipulations on the dayTime, since all you care is the number of records the aggregation will hold.

As for the second query, you will need to Join tables "Course" and "Teacher", again by course Number.

Both queries should use Group By and Having clauses, since you need aggregation in both which is conditioned in the number of teachers / Weekly meetings.

Hope this helps.

```
drop table #Teacher
SELECT  *
into #Teacher
FROM    
(
    select 1 as CourseN, 1 as Quarter, 'Dan' as TeacherName
        union
    select 1 as CourseN, 1 as Quarter, 'Alex' as TeacherName
        union
    select 2 as CourseN, 1 as Quarter, 'Rob' as TeacherName
        union
    select 3 as CourseN, 2 as Quarter, 'Jim' as TeacherName
        union
    select 4 as CourseN, 3 as Quarter, 'Bob' as TeacherName
        union
    select 4 as CourseN, 3 as Quarter, 'Alice' as TeacherName
) a

drop table #Course
SELECT  *
into #Course
FROM    
(
select 1 as CourseN, 'English' as CourseName, 1 as Nunit
    UNION
select 2 as CourseN, 'Algebra' as CourseName, 1 as Nunit
    UNION
select 3 as CourseN, 'Math' as CourseName, 1 as Nunit
    UNION
select 4 as CourseN, 'Science' as CourseName, 1 as Nunit
) a


drop table #Section
SELECT  *
into #Section
FROM    
(
    select 1 as CourseN, 1 as Quarter, 'M2:00AM' as DayTime , 1 as RoomN
        UNION
    select 1 as CourseN, 1 as Quarter, 'W2:00AM' as DayTime , 1 as RoomN
        UNION
    select 2 as CourseN, 1 as Quarter, 'W2:00AM' as DayTime , 1 as RoomN
        UNION
    select 3 as CourseN, 2 as Quarter, 'W2:00AM' as DayTime , 1 as RoomN
        UNION
    select 3 as CourseN, 2 as Quarter, 'T2:00AM' as DayTime , 1 as RoomN
        UNION
    select 4 as CourseN, 3 as Quarter, 'T2:00AM' as DayTime , 1 as RoomN
) a


--List the CourseN, CourseName, and Quarter which meets or met at least  two times a week.
select a.CourseN , a.CourseName , b.Quarter --, COUNT(b.CourseN) NumOfWeeklyMeetings
from #Course a
    inner join #Section b
        on a.CourseN = b.CourseN
Where 1=1
GROUP BY a.CourseN , a.CourseName , b.Quarter
having COUNT(b.CourseN) > 1


--List the CourseN and Quarter of every course taught by two 
--different instructors in the same quarter ordered by the CourseN in descending order.
SELECT  a.CourseN , b.Quarter --, count(b.TeacherName) NumOfTeachers
FROM    #Course a
    inner join #Teacher b 
        on a.CourseN = b.CourseN
WHERE 1=1
group by a.CourseN , b.Quarter
having count(b.TeacherName) > 1
```

Comment: thank you for all the trouble, ive actually already made my own database tables in access, and i know i had to do something like that, but the thing is it own let me put duplicates and I really confused on what everyones saying about connecting Teacher table with Course table, i did set courseN as the primary key for both of these but im guessing thats the reason why it wont let me put duplicate courseN's in Teacher table

Comment: I think you are missing something.

Course table is a 1-1 table (I'm only guessing since it sounds logical).
That means each course will have a single corresponding record.

However, Teacher table is 1-N table, as many teachers can teach a single course.

This means the CourseN in Teacher table, is the foreign Key to Course table, for joining the two.

Makes sense?

Comment: Edit!! Ive narrowed it down on why its giving me that error, i cant have duplicate Quarter  and courseN in the Teachers database table. But i can have duplicate courseN and different quarters and vise versa.And i know it doesnt show in the info part of the question but courseN and Quarter is underlined letting us know that they are primary keys, so now that i know that what should i do to let me have duplicate quarters in the Teachers table?